# Can I edit and remove non related links from POSTS?

Tags: support

Some users post their personal sites (might be for promotion) on their posts (both Q & A) *which are completely non related to question*. I can't downvote the post because of the links.

So Can I edit and remove such link(s), If the remaining post seems OK ?

Now my Edits to any question or answer are applied immediately. So I need to be very careful.

Suggest me the right behavior.

Find out such posts in the following(answers)

1) https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/126673/25879

2) https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/126671/25879

**Edit:**

I've deleted the "promotion link" from above 1st link . So here is the revision

https://drupal.stackexchange.com/posts/126673/revisions

What should I do? Can I report this to diamond moderators?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Removing signatures is an acceptable edit, as is removing overt-self promotion.  This is explained in the [help center](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).

If you see repeated self-promotions from a users, flag with a custom reason, and explain what is going on.

Please remember, though, that we do allow *related* links.  Users can link out to their own blog posts to support answers, and users can recommend modules that they maintain.  However, in both of these cases the link is to support the answer and should not be the main content of the answer.

Comment: Great! thanks I got the complete answer :)

Comment: Yes I know that. That's why I mentioned non-related links in my post :) Thanks for the detailed answer.